# Double ISBLANK statement in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to return two different values based on two cells, not consecutive, and whether they are blank or not. If one is blank, then i just want the regular old blank cell displayed, otherwise do an equation. I have that working ok. I want to add another formula that if a second cell is blank, still return the first formula or if it is populated, then return "Done".

Here is what i have so far:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(X3)),"",(X3-30)*-1)
```

Now I need to add if Y3 is not blank, then return "Done", otherwise if still blank, carry on with the first function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for nested **IF** function:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Y3),IF(ISBLANK(X3),"",(X3-30)*-1),"Done")
```